# How to implement useState function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-development-server

I am trying to implement useState function from a tutorial.

```
  const [posts, setposts] = useState([
    { username:"cleverqazi",
      caption:"wow it works",
      imageUrl:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/5624397/pexels-photo-5624397.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",},
    
    {  username:"its_cleverqazi",
       caption:"wow it ",
       imageUrl:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/5624397/pexels-photo-5624397.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" }
   ]);
```

```
 {
    posts.map(post=> {
     return <Post username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl}  />
    })
  }
```

I was expecting to implement useState function, and show the data.
But nothing shows.

Comment: Open dev tools and read the errors

Comment: mmm looks like you didn't return the Post. try posts.map(post=> { *return*
      <Post username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl}  />
    })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return

```
<Post />
```

And add a Key/index value when using Map
Meaning:

```
 {
    posts.map((data, index) => {
       return <Post key={index} username={data.username} caption={data.caption} imageUrl={data.imageUrl}  />
    })
  }
```